# Error during the kernel booting

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

After kernel update I've got a problem with booting linux, does anyone know how to fix this problem ?? I am pretty sure that everything was OK during kernel compilation.

Here is a picture with the error :

[image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2jakgab.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to your new kernel not having a driver for your file system. Details on your disk/controller along with your `.config` would help us determine whether this is the case.

It could also be initramfs thinking that devtmpfs is available when it is not. If this is the case, add `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y` to your `.config`

Comment: My file system is ext4, (On my server I can setup just : ext4, ext3, btrfs, reiserfs so I pick ext4 on both partition) it's just one HDD connected to the motherboard by SATA cable. Should I change my file system to ext3 ?? I will add "CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y" to my .config file next time.

Comment: btw. the rest of .config file should be fine, because I did make defconfig before make menuconfig, and in the config menu I just enable the grsecurity